# When $\frac{\pi ^{x}}{\zeta (x)}$ is rational?

Tags: riemann-zeta, rational-numbers

When $n$ is a positive integer, we know

$$\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$

Now let's say $x>1$ is a real number. Can we say if $\frac{\pi ^{x}}{\zeta (x)}$ is a rational number then x must be an even integer?

Comment: If the function is invertible for some range, it takes an infinity of rational values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not. $\frac{\pi^x}{\zeta(x)}$ is continuous on at least $x\in[3,4)$ (just giving a counterexample here), and non-constant, thus, it'll have rational values for some $x\in[3,4)$ (and so $x$ is not an even integer)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Since it is not relevant what interval that is as long as it doesn't contain even integers, I was a bit sloppy in my choice. I edited my answer to another interval